# Limit firestore document creation by one document per user using firebase rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a `Questions` collection. Inside it is a nested collection `Responses`. Therefore, all responses to a particular question can be found inside that particular document.

I have to limit the users from sending more than one response to the same question.

Currently, I am doing this on the server-side **(admin-SDK)** by saving the `uid` of the user in the response document.

```js
 firestore
    .collection("questions")
    .doc(questionID)
    .collection("responses")
    .where("uid", "==", AuthUser.id)
    .get().then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.docs.length == 0) {
        let createdAt = Date.now()
        firestore
            .collection("questions")
            .doc(questionID)
            .collection("responses")
            .add({
              uid: AuthUser.id,
              answer,
              createdAt,
              updatedAt: createdAt
        }).then(() => {
            return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Success' })
        })
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'You cannot send more than one response' })
      }
    })
```

Is there any way to achieve this behavior with the firebase security-rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to have users write to a document with ID equal to their user ID, instead of a random ID. If you don't store the userId in the ID of the document, then you would have to iterate over all existing responses in order to check if the user is submitting more than one response.

```js
firestore
    .collection("questions")
    .doc(questionID)
    .collection("responses")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .set({ ..... })
```

If you make users write to documents with IDs matching their user ID, it's pretty simple to structure your rules such that people can only edit their own response.

Here's a sample that allows anybody to read responses, and people to only create/update/delete their own document. This ensures they can only submit one response, since they can only write to data at this one key.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /Questions/{questionId}/responses/{responseId} {

    allow create, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == responseId;
    allow read: if true;
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: As your answer says, it's the easiest way to do this. I only thought about how I could do this by changing `security-rules` and never thought of changing the **document structure**. Thanks you.